# On the functional form of Kullback-Leibler information

Tags: statistics, information-theory

I'm studying about information criteria and came across with the following proof in my [reference material](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387718866) (page 34):

> **On the functional form of Kullback-Leibler information**
>
> If the differentiable function $F$ defined on $(0, \infty)$ satisfies
>   the relationship
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^k g_iF(f_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^k g_iF(g_i)$$
>
> for any two probability functions $\{g_1, ..., g_k\}$ and $\{f_1, ...,
> f_k\}$, then $F(g)=\alpha + \beta\log g$ for some $\alpha, \beta$ with
>    $\beta>0$.
>
> **Proof:**  In order to demonstrate that $F (g) = \alpha + \beta \log g$,
>   it suffices to show that $gF'(g)=\beta>0$ and hence that $\partial F /
>  \partial g =\beta/g$
>
> Let $h = (h_1, ..., h_k)^T$ be an arbitrary vector that satisfies
>   $\sum_{i=1}^k h_i=0$ and $|h_i| \leq \max\{g_i , 1 − g_i\}$. Since
>   $g+\lambda h$ is a probability distribution, it follows from the
>   assumption that
>
> $$\phi(\lambda)\equiv \sum_{i=1}^k g_iF(g_i+\lambda h_i) \leq
>  \sum_{i=1}^k g_iF(g_i)=\phi(0).$$
>
> Therefore, since
>
> $$\phi'(\lambda)= \sum_{i=1}^k g_iF'(g_i+\lambda
>  h_i)h_i,\;\;\;\;{\color{red}{\phi'(0)= \sum_{i=1}^k g_iF'(g_i)h_i=0}}$$
>
> are always true, by writing $h_1=C, h_2=-C, h_i=0\;(i=3, ..., k)$, we
>   have
>
> $$g_1F'(g_1)=g_2F'(g_2)=\text{const}=\beta.$$
>
> The equality for other values of $i$ can be shown in a similar manner
>   Q.E.D.

**QUESTION 1: What happened starting from the equation I marked as red? Why is this equation equal to zero?**

**QUESTION 2: It was not given in my material but I assume the values $\lambda$ and $C$ are constants?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the red equation it was used the fact, written above, that for all $\lambda$ (at least the ones for which the function is well defined)
$$ \phi(\lambda) \leq \phi(0)$$
This means that $\phi$ attains maximum at $0$ and therefore its derivative at $0$ must be $0$.

To answer the second question: no, $\lambda$ is not a constant. Once the vector $h$ is fixed, we define the function 
$$\lambda\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^k g_iF(g_i+\lambda h_i)$$
Observe that, since we required $h$ to satisfy the properties above, for all $\lambda$ sufficiently small $(g_i+\lambda h_i)$ is a probability function (at least for $\vert\lambda\vert<1$, otherwise there is the risk that for some $i$ $g_i+\lambda h_i<0$, and in that case we cannot evaluate it in $F$). So we can consider $\lambda$ to be a variable in $(-1,1)$.

Now all of this reasoning was done for a fixed suitable vector $h$ (i.e. a different choice of $h$ would determine a different function $\phi$). Now $C$ is a constant (which again has to be sufficiently small for everything to be well defined) that we choose, and that determines $h$ of the form $(C,-C,0,\ldots,0)$. What they do then is to plug in the equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^k g_iF'(g_i)h_i =0$$
the vector $h=(C,-C,0,\ldots,0)$ which gives
$$Cg_1 F'(g_1) - Cg_2 F'(g_2)=0$$
and the conclusion follows. I hope this clarifies it to you.

Comment: One more question about the function $f = \{f_1, ..., f_k\}$. The author says that this can be **any** probability function. I understand this as so that I can for example set $f \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. But in the proof we give the conditions that $\lambda \in (-1, 1)$ and $\sum h_i = 0$ etc. so $f_i=g_i+\lambda h_i$ seems to be more restricted than just being any probability function?

Comment: Furthermore, why do we need the assumption $\beta > 0 $?

Comment: $f$ is any probability function on $\{1,\ldots, k\}$, so it's a discrete probability function. You can see it as a collection of $k$ numbers in $[0,1]$ with total sum $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i=1$. In that sense it cannot be a normal, since it wouldn't be a discrete probability. We are not assuming $\beta>0$, that is part of the statement, i.e. part of the conclusion. Actually there is a typo, because the right conclusion is $\beta\geq 0$ ($\beta=0$ is the degenerate case in which $F$ is constant).

Comment: Thank you @Lucio for you help. Sorry if my questions are simple. I always want to get things 100% :)

Comment: Anyways, why do we have $\beta \geq 0$? :)

Comment: In order to show that $\beta\geq 0$, you can take $(g_1,\ldots,g_n)=(1,0,\ldots,0)$ and plug it in the initial inequality (even if $F$ is non defined at $0$ i guess you have some condition $0F(0)=0$) and you get $F(f_1)\leq F(1)$. Now since we have shown that $F(g)=\alpha +\beta\log g$, this implies $\beta\log f_1\leq 0$ and so since $\log f_1 <0$ implies $\beta\geq 0$.

Comment: That nailed it, excellent job! :)

Comment: Your welcome @jjepsuomi :). Sorry if I didn't answer immediately to both questions but the comment would have been too long. Don't worry, it's normal to have doubts in proofs, any question is legitimate.

Comment: I understand, no problem. You did good job! :)